# Transferring object messages between Java app and Scala app via Akka

Tags: java, scala, akka

I have two projects. First is written in Java and uses Akka whereas the second one is a Scala project and it makes use of Akka actors as well. I've established a successful connection between the two in terms of sending common objects and fields(i.e `String`). What I want is be able to send custom `Object`s such as `User` in between. Thus, Java side would simply have entities, and the Scala side would have `Case classes` respectively.

#### Java:

1.User.java:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  public final String name;
  public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User [name=" + name + "]";
  }
}
```

2.Hello App class:

```
public class Boot {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem system;
    ActorSelection remoteActor;

    Config config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("hello");
    system = ActorSystem.create("HelloApplication");

    String remoteAcPath = config.getString("remote-user-actor");
    remoteUserHandleActor = system.actorSelection(remoteAcPath);

    User u = new User("Alex");

    System.out.println("Sending message to Remote Actor ...");
    remoteUserHandleActor.tell(u, userActor);
  }
}
```

#### Scala

1.User case class:

```
case class User(val name: String) extends Serializable
```

2.Hello App:

```
object Boot extends App {

  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  lazy implicit val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloServer")
  val userActor = system.actorOf(Props[UserHandleActor], name = "userHandlerActor")
}
```

Sending a message with Java actor to Scala actor casues following **dead letters** error in Java side:

```
[HelloApplication-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] INFO  akka.actor.LocalActorRef - Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://HelloApplication/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://HelloApplication/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FHelloServer%40127.0.0.1%3A1111-1#-1775289115] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[HelloApplication-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO  akka.actor.LocalActorRef - Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://HelloApplication/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://HelloApplication/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FHelloServer%40127.0.0.1%3A1111-1#-1775289115] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Scala side shows this message:

```
31/10/2013 09:04:38 UTC | DEBUG | Remoting HelloServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 - Associated [akka.tcp://HelloServer@127.0.0.1:1111] <- [akka.tcp://HelloApplication@192.162.1.4:2552]
31/10/2013 09:04:38 UTC | DEBUG | akka.remote.EndpointWriter HelloServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 - Disassociated [akka.tcp://HelloServer@127.0.0.1:1111] <- [akka.tcp://HelloApplication@192.162.1.4:2552]
31/10/2013 09:04:38 UTC | INFO  | akka.actor.LocalActorRef HelloServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 - Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://HelloServer/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://HelloServer/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FHelloApplication%40192.162.1.4%3A2552-0/endpointWriter/endpointReader-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FHelloApplication%40192.162.1.4%3A2552-0#526150656] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
31/10/2013 09:04:38 UTC | INFO  | akka.actor.LocalActorRef HelloServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 - Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://HelloServer/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://HelloServer/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FHelloServer%40127.0.0.1%3A54194-1#-802595184] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
31/10/2013 09:04:38 UTC | DEBUG | akka.remote.EndpointWriter HelloServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6 - Associated [akka.tcp://HelloServer@127.0.0.1:1111] -> [akka.tcp://HelloApplication@192.162.1.4:2552]
31/10/2013 09:04:38 UTC | DEBUG | Remoting HelloServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 - Associated [akka.tcp://HelloServer@127.0.0.1:1111] <- [akka.tcp://HelloApplication@192.162.1.4:2552]
```

Afterwards, I came up with a crazy idea that I set the same `serialVersionUID` (i.e. `serialVersionUID = 888L`) to User.java entity and User case class, and interestingly, messages are successfully handled and everything is fine. I know that at this point I am doing wrong with that serialization.

1) What is the best bet of achieving my goal?

2) If there are ways of converting custom objects between Java and Scala (I know of `javaconversions` which is for collections and the like) that will be super.

#### Edit

3) Is my *crazy idea* of setting the same `serialVersionUID` in both sides proper?

Comment: I would introduce DTOs in a shared java project and both your scala and java app should use those for transferring data.

Comment: @mr.boyfox right, I don't want to use java class in scala project, too. Is not that another way of? –

Comment: I don't really see any other "architecturally clean" choice here. Think about refactoring and maintainability as well. What will guarantee that your java and scala classes are in sync all the time?

Comment: Many people say write own serializer class(and use google protobuf), but this is right way or not

Comment: Write your own serializer and use protobuf or similar is a possible solution. As mentioned, shared java classes is another solution.

Comment: I would argue against custom serialization based solution. This will only work when remoting is in play. If the two sides happen to be in the same JVM, everything will crash. One of the fundamental ideas in Akka is location transparency. Relying on the fact that the two actors are in different processes is clearly against it.

Comment: Statement `ConfigFactory.load` load `application.conf` from default location. Could you please add this/these file/files for *java Hello App* and *scala Hello App* to question?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use Java classes in both projects and provide some layer over them so that they can be used in Scala almost like they were case classes.

For example, assuming you only have a Java version of `User` class, you can do this on the Scala side:

```
object User {
  // will allow you to create User instances without the 'new' keyword
  def apply(name: String) = 
    new User(name)

  // will allow you to pattern-match against User instances, for example in
  // actor's 'receive' function
  def unapply(user: User) = 
    Some(user.name)

  // implicit wrapper that will add some Scala-like API to your User class
  implicit class UserScalaApi(user: User) {
    // whatever you need here (the 'copy' method, etc.)
  }
}
```

The downside of this is that you have to create such adaptation layer for every Java class (macro annotations would be so awesome here...).